# Solving $x = \left(\frac{ab}{cd}\right)^{0.68}$ for $a$.

Tags: exponential-function, fractions

My equation is $$x = \left(\frac{ab}{cd}\right)^{0.68}.$$

How do I find $a$? I am out of ideas here.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to isolate $a$ in your expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For $x\ge 0$:
$$
\left(\frac{ab}{cd}\right)^{\frac{68}{100}}=x\quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{ab}{cd}=x^{\frac{100}{68}}
$$

now find $a$

Comment: How did you go from $0.68$ to $\frac{68}{100}$? And $\frac{68}{100}=\frac{17}{25}$.

Comment: Raise both sides to the 100th power to get $(\frac{ab}{cd})^(68)$ = $x^(100)$, then raise both sides to the power of 1/68.

Comment: @AndreasAlmgren: do you know that $0.68=\frac{68}{100}$? And the reduced fraction is the same number.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Oh well, that is true <Blush> +1

Answer (score 1):

We have $\log(x)=0.68\log\left(\frac{ab}{cd}\right)=0.68(\log(a)+\log(b)-\log(cd))$ implies that
$$\begin{align}a&=e^{\frac{100}{68}\log(x)+\log(cd)-\log(b)}\\
&=\frac{x^{\frac{100}{68}}cd}{b}.
\end{align}$$

This is assuming $b\neq 0$.